# When do you integrate Acceptance Testing into a scrum process?

Tags: testing, scrum

I want to know exactly when I can integrate acceptance testing into a scrum process? During the sprint cycle or at the end of the sprint cycle?

I know that acceptance testing is when we test the software against the user requirements, but i want to know exactly when acceptance tests should be done in the scrum process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The team should produce a potentially shippable increment

[The Development Team consists of professionals who do the work of delivering a potentially releasable Increment of “Done” product at the end of each Sprint...with all of the skills as a team necessary to create a product Increment.](https://www.scrum.org/Portals/0/Documents/Scrum%20Guides/2013/Scrum-Guide.pdf)

The team should produce a "potentially shippable increment" at the end of the sprint. Without testing whatever the team produces is not shippable.

> but i want to know exactly when acceptance tests are done into scrum
>   process...During the sprint cycle or at the end of the sprint cycle?

As @Bryan Oakley said you should do acceptance testing during the sprint.

> is it possible to separate the team, i.e team for development and team
>   for testing? For example: from the first Sprint Planning we separates
>   them, team 1 for development and team 2 for testing, working at the
>   same time.

No, they should not be separate teams. The team needs all the skills needed to create a "potentially shippable increment" - design, dev, testing...etc - within the team.

Scrum does not allow separate testing teams. In fact, Scrum does not even allow testing sub-teams within the development team! Here is the quote from the Scrum Guide by Jeff Sutherland and Ken Schwaber, "Scrum recognizes no sub-teams in the Development Team, regardless of particular domains that need to be addressed like testing or business analysis; there are no exceptions to this rule".

Comment: I don't agree that Scrum doesn't allow separate testing teams. It is perfectly acceptable to have specialists on an agile team. And I suspect a lot of productivity has been lost by teams pursuing some false holy grail of having each team member able to do everything.

Answer (score 2):

During the sprint cycle.

If you are doing automated testing, the team members writing the tests can begin to write them either before or as the software is being developed.

If you are not writing automated tests, the testers can begin at the start of the sprint by working on their test plans, getting familiar with the new requirements, etc.

Comment: it is possible to separate the team, i.e team for development and team for testing?

For example: from the first Sprint Planning we separates them, team 1 for development and team 2 for testing, working at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Acceptance tests should be done by Product managers, SME/clients. To gain confidence about the product, acceptance tests should be integrated during the sprint.

Typically we will have a feature creation sprint  for UAT followed by stabilization sprints for UAT, the user story used in feature creation sprint needs to be repeated during stabilization sprints to get more confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I also agree that acceptance tests should be done outside of your scrum team.

It's done for the team, they have done the testing cycle within the sprint, but I would recommend a key user test team testing the software before going to live.

It also depends on the kind of software you are making. If you don't have a key user test team, or your key users are web site visitors then there is no other option to test it yourself (together with the product owner / or just by the product owner)